# batch file sub routine

Tags: batch-file, subroutine

I'm trying to re-use the batch file code in order to perform a similar tasks in a menu pages.

The main menu consists of 10+ options. 
When I go inside the each menu items, I need to display a following in text

```
Press [C] to Continue or [X] to exit [C/X]: _
```

I created labels in each menu time and re-direct to the code which is responsible for prompting the message and do necessary actions.

How can I use this following code as a subroutine, so that I don't have to re-write the code several times.At the moment I hard code it in each menu item. It would have been easy to call it as a sub routine.

```
:MiniMenu1
SET INPUT1=
SET /P INPUT1=Press [Y] to Continue Installation or [N] to go back [Y/N]:
IF /I '%INPUT1%'=='y' GOTO Mini_cont1
IF /I '%INPUT1%'=='n' GOTO Mini_back1
ECHO ============INVALID INPUT============
ECHO Please select a number from the Menu Options
ECHO -------------------------------------
ECHO ======PRESS ANY KEY TO CONTINUE======

PAUSE > NUL
GOTO MiniMenu1
```

Where as my code for main menu item pages are

```
:Selection1
:: MAin menu item 1
   GOTO MiniMenu1
:Mini_cont1
:: xCopy update.zip C:\python27\ /y
@echo Update Completed.
 pause 
:Mini_back1
:: end
GOTO MENU
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah - thinking along the right lines. Very good.

```
@echo off
setlocal
call :ask Question number one
if errorlevel 2 goto Q1X
call :ask Question number two
if errorlevel 2 goto Q2X
::get here for Q1Q2 responses both C
goto :eof

:ask
choice /c CX /N /M "%*"
goto :eof
```

Here's a basic template. From the prompt, type `choice /?` for instructions about options.

Hint: `set "choices=wqzk"` then in the subroutine `choice /c %choices% /N /M "%*"` would allow you to change the choices available. `/n` prompts with the available choices, so you've no need to specify that in the text, just make it obvious - `Whatever, Quit, Zap, Kill` should be obvious for `wqzk` for instance.

The return in `%errorlevel%` will the the sequence-number of the character chosen. W==>1, Q==>2..K==>4. In the traditional construct, `if errorlevel n` the comparison is true if `errorlevel` is `n` **or greater than** `n` so it would be traditional to use

```
if errorlevel 4 goto QnA4
if errorlevel 3 goto QnA3
if errorlevel 2 goto QnA2
:: if it gets here, errorlevel is 1 hence choice was first character.
```

which is shorter than the "modern" way

```
if %errorlevel%==1 goto QnA1
if %errorlevel%==2 goto QnA2
if %errorlevel%==3 goto QnA3
:: if it gets here, errorlevel is 4 or more hence choice was fourth or later character.
```

Note: `%*` means `all of the arguments passed to the subroutine` so `/m "%*"` neatly shows the arguments passed as a prompt. There's no voodoo about that. But be careful - text only and a few symbols if you like. Symbols with a special meaning to `cmd` *may cause unexpected results*

---

Variables created/changed/deleted after a `setlocal` will be deleted/restored/resurrected when a matching `endlocal` is encountered. Consequently, `setlocal` is often used as the first "action statement" in a batch - the environment is restored to pristine when the batch ends.

To remove variables within a batch using a subroutine, you could use

```
call :zap we dont want these variables

:zap
if "%1" neq "" set "%1="&shift&goto zap
goto :eof
```

(to delete variables `we` `dont` `want` `these` and  `variables`

or `:zap version 2`

```
:zap
for %%a in (%*) do set "%%a="
goto :eof
```

To remove variables which all start with an identical character-pattern, use

```
FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="
```

(which will remove all variables starting `$`. `$` isn't holy - you could substitute `xyz` for `$` here and zap `xyz123` `xyz789` and `xyzylofone` for instance)

Naturally, you could also combine the techniques...

But - it's not expensive to ask a new question on SO. Not expensive at all. Cheap even. Asking a new question rather than tagging more issues onto an existing one makes finding a solution easier (like.. someone wanting to know how to delete variables possibly wouldn't expect to find it under a question titled "batch file sub routine" for instance. It also prevents the question from becoming a *saga*.

Comment: Thanks it works. How can I clear the variables defined under  setlocal, in case if they are stored When I call the sub routine again.